# Why does this work, and why is it wrong?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have devised a "proof" that $i=0$. Obviously it can't be true, but I can't see why it is wrong. I've been thinking about this for a while, and my friend and I are very confused. What is wrong with the "proof" below?

$e^{i\pi} = -1$
$e^{2i\pi} = 1$
$2i\pi = ln(1)$
$i = \frac{0}{2\pi}$
$i = 0$

Comment: This is bound to be a duplicate. But a quick answer in comment form nevertheless. You are abusing $\ln$ very badly here. How much do you know about logarithms on complex numbers? I'd recommend you read the complex logarithm article on wikipedia which should answer all your questions. Basically your issue is that log on complex numbers is not a function in general. Same as inverse to sine on reals isn't a function. You need to choose a branch where you will invert. What you did here is you used two different branches at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you have proved in the second line $e^{2i\pi} = 1=e^0$, so the complex exponential function is not injective. Thus you can not define a complex log function as its inverse function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that natural log is actually a multi-valued function over the complex numbers and there is no way to even make it a smooth single-valued function without removing a so-called "branch cut" where the function is undefined.